# Select column slice from multi-level column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,30)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022],['A','B','C']])
```

I have data for year from 2013 to 2022 and each year has three sub categories.
I want to choose the year from 2018 to 2022.
I tried the below code but couldnt get what i wanted.

```
dF.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[['2018','2019','2020','2021','2022'], :]]
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0)== ['2018','2019','2020','2021','2022']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want years 2018 to 2022 with their sub categories:

```
df.loc[:, '2018':'2022']
```

Output:

```
       2018                          2019                          2020                          2021                          2022
          A         B         C         A         B         C         A         B         C         A         B         C         A         B         C
0  0.668522  0.399556  0.835691  0.371684  0.223578  0.508556  0.894202  0.010591  0.031752  0.266423  0.096535  0.541736  0.478333  0.500708  0.047695
1  0.788600  0.247423  0.486000  0.103808  0.189844  0.103619  0.770656  0.227629  0.142186  0.345041  0.736736  0.709567  0.387760  0.115924  0.583976
2  0.532269  0.830621  0.824949  0.715607  0.447571  0.120088  0.730780  0.988936  0.874577  0.896597  0.858540  0.963164  0.066408  0.927972  0.583064
3  0.554343  0.330159  0.480898  0.082837  0.125676  0.993155  0.494752  0.885078  0.987041  0.198048  0.773472  0.269203  0.908859  0.021497  0.449397
4  0.625704  0.244451  0.816690  0.465161  0.970303  0.782911  0.473847  0.241617  0.031159  0.953216  0.418353  0.882098  0.020776  0.983628  0.661943
```